# ChartJS distinguish clicks between chart area, dataset and legend

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a react app that uses ChartJS through 'npm react-chartjs-2'.
I am working with a `Line` chart and I a have the following requirements:

1- Detect clicking on chart area (white area; other than data set line, and legend), then do some logic

2- Detect clicking on legend rectangle at the top to hide/show the dataset (current default behaviour)

I have tried using `options.onClick` but it seems to override legend click.
Also tried `getElementAtEvent` it returns the dataset clicked on but when clicking on legend/chart area comes as empty. `getDatasetAtEvent` always return empty array. And if I use `options.legend.onClick` I loose default hide/show behaviour and need to do it programmatically.

I was wondering is there is a better way to achieve requirements above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getElementsAtEvent property. This gives value only when the chart area is clicked, the element is null if it is clicked on the legend. If it is clicked on the chart area then it holds properties from which we can get the clicked xAxis and legend value.

```
document.getElementById("yourChartCanvasId").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var element = instance.getElementsAtEvent(e)[0];

    if (element) {    
      //Handle click on chart area        
    }
    else {    
      //Handle click on legend area        
    }        
});
```

Also if you don't want to do anything on legend click, keeping the default Chart.js behavior then don't include the else block.

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work..clicking on white space or legend `element` will be undefined..`element` is valid only if clicking on data points.